# How to install Snap on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I mistakenly uninstalled the inbuilt snap from my Ubuntu, i want to reinstall it, can anybody help me in it. i tried researching several websites, but didn't found any way to install snap again.

Comment: Can't you install it by executing `apt install snapd`?

Comment: @vsergi no, i am getting the error of broken dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Install Snap by "apt install snapd"...

For Reference : https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-your-first-snap#1-overview

Hope it would be useful for you :)

Comment: getting error on broken dependancies